# How could two independent clauses join together with no conjunction or semicolon?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, grammaticality-in-context

> Big stock-market gains are leading a number of investors to abandon defensive positions taken to protect against a market downturn, **the latest sign that many doubters are shedding caution as the long rally rolls on**.

I was taught that two independent cannot be joined together unless we put a **semicolon** or conjunction or conjunctival adverbs.

My question how could the bold line join what came before without being preceded by a conjunction or semicolon.

Comment: The bold part is not an independent clause.  An independent clause is one that could stand alone as a sentence, but "The latest sign that many doubters are shedding caution as the long rally rolls on" doesn't have a main verb.

Comment: Does that mean the bold line is subordinate clause “ dependent” ? @stangdon  or what is called?

Comment: The bold text is not a clause at all, it is a noun phrase (that happens to contain an embedded clause) in appostion to "a market downturn".

Comment: The noun-phrase is an adjunct that supplies additional information about  the main clause, about investors **abandoning defensive positions to protect against a market downturn** because of big market gains; that abandonment [is understood to be] *the latest sign that many doubters are shedding caution....*   The noun- phrase adds something about the whole shebang.

Comment: *People are waiting in line for days to buy tickets to see their favorite bands, a sign that the world is going to hell in a handbasket.*

Comment: As Colin Fine said, the bold text is an apposition.

Comment: @ColinFine You should write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, you are correct that independent clauses cannot be joined without a comma conjunction or a semicolon. This passage, however, does not contain two independent clauses; could the bold section stand on its own, without the preceding text?

> the latest sign that many doubters are shedding caution as the long rally rolls on.

If we try to parse this as a sentence, we realize that it is actually all part of the subject (a long noun phrase), with no accompanying predicate. The apparent verbs "shedding" and "rolls" are actually part of an extended description of the noun "sign" - they tell us what the sign is, not what it is doing.